# Modifying a symbol with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I need to replicate this two symbols with XeLaTeX.

[image][image]

I was able to do the tick sign using `fontspec` in this way:

```
\newfontface\WingFont
  {Wingdings 2}
\newcommand{\Tick}{\text{\WingFont\char"F050}}
```

How can I put the cross and double cross signs? Thank you for any help you may give me.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). It's will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am sorry: I thought the code was not necessary to solve this problem. Next time I will post a compilable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to make your own cross and double-cross symbols using `\rule`. Then you can use `\ooalign` to overlay the crosses with your chosen tick mark. Here is an example with `\checkmark` from the `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\onemark}{\raisebox{.7ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{\rule{.4em}{.1ex}}}}
\newcommand{\twomark}{\raisebox{.5ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{\rule{.4em}{.1ex}\hspace{-.4em}\rule[.4ex]{.4em}{.1ex}}}}
\newcommand{\Tick}{\checkmark}
\newcommand{\Ticka}{{\ooalign{\Tick\cr\hfil\onemark\hfil\cr}}}
\newcommand{\Tickb}{{\ooalign{\Tick\cr\hfil\twomark\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}
\Tick\Ticka\Tickb
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the length (`.4em`), thickness (`.1ex`) and spacing (`.4ex`) of the crosses to your liking. I used `ex` and `em` units so the tick marks will adjust to `\Large` or other size commands.